# Clear read error on SSD

Tags: ssd, smartctl

My SSD gives this:

```
$ smartctl -a /dev/sdg
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-67-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Crucial/Micron BX/MX1/2/3/500, M5/600, 1100 SSDs
Device Model:     Crucial_CT525MX300SSD1
Serial Number:    1711164B7A3E
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00a075 1164b7a3e
Firmware Version: M0CR040
User Capacity:    525,112,713,216 bytes [525 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Apr 14 22:11:44 2021 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x04) Offline data collection activity
                                        was suspended by an interrupting command from host.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                ( 1114) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   8) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x0035) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       458
  5 Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt 0x0032   090   090   010    Old_age   Always       -       168
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9593
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       730
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       61
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Ave_Block-Erase_Count   0x0032   088   088   000    Old_age   Always       -       183
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       241
183 SATA_Interfac_Downshift 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
184 Error_Correction_Count  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4195967
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   066   049   000    Old_age   Always       -       34 (Min/Max 17/51)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       168
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       6
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Percent_Lifetime_Remain 0x0030   088   088   001    Old_age   Offline      -       12
206 Write_Error_Rate        0x000e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       61
246 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       48747389732
247 Host_Program_Page_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1523636483
248 FTL_Program_Page_Count  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4535443961
180 Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk 0x0033   000   000   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       1781
210 Success_RAIN_Recov_Cnt  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1488

SMART Error Log Version: 1
Warning: ATA error count 1663 inconsistent with error log pointer 2

ATA Error Count: 1663 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 1663 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 a0 52 5e 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x005e52a0 = 6181536

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 a0 52 5e 40 08  44d+02:41:25.408  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 40 61 40 08  44d+02:41:25.408  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 b0 d8 40 08  44d+02:41:25.408  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 68 88 af 78 40 08  44d+02:41:25.408  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 00 af 78 40 08  44d+02:41:25.408  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 1662 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 d8 52 5e 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x005e52d8 = 6181592

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 d8 52 5e 40 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  47 00 01 30 06 00 e0 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 30 00 00 e0 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 00 00 00 e0 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 30 08 00 e0 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ LOG DMA EXT

Error 1661 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 d8 52 5e 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x005e52d8 = 6181592

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 d8 52 5e 40 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  47 00 01 30 06 00 e0 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 30 00 00 e0 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 00 00 00 e0 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 30 08 00 e0 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ LOG DMA EXT

Error 1660 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 d8 52 5e 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x005e52d8 = 6181592

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 d8 52 5e 40 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  47 00 01 30 06 00 e0 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 30 00 00 e0 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 00 00 00 e0 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 30 08 00 e0 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ LOG DMA EXT

Error 1659 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 d8 52 5e 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x005e52d8 = 6181592

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 d8 52 5e 40 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  47 00 01 30 06 00 e0 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 30 00 00 e0 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 00 00 00 e0 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 30 08 00 e0 08  44d+02:40:25.408  READ LOG DMA EXT

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      9591         -
# 2  Offline             Completed without error       00%      9573         -
# 3  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      9571         -
# 4  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      9505         -
# 5  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      9337         -
# 6  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      9169         -
# 7  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      9002         -
# 8  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      8834         -
# 9  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      8834         -
#10  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      8666         -
#11  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      8666         -
#12  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      8498         -
#13  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      8330         -
#14  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      8330         -
#15  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      8162         -
#16  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      8162         -
#17  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      7994         -
#18  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      7826         -
#19  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      7658         -
#20  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      7490         -
#21  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      7405         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

But `pv` works with no errors:

```
pv /dev/sdg >/dev/null
```

I have the feeling that the read error has been fixed - possibly by overwriting the block.

So how can I clear the error, so that `smartd` does not complain?

Comment: You fix a read error by rewriting the block. The firmware will then reallocate it elsewhere

Comment: What *complaint* of `smartd` exactly do you want to get rid of? When your SSD was able to fix the logical block by storing it elsewhere on rewrite, then the error report is still valuable information about the state of your device.

Comment: @Bodo I do not want an email every day saying `smartd` found 6 uncorrectable errors, when reading the full disk shows these have been corrected.